# What is this strange symbol in this IC block diagram that looks like a rectangle inside a buffer?

Tags: integrated-circuit, schematics, diagram, block-diagram

I am not sure what the below symbols of a buffer looking symbol with a rectangle inside are:

[image]

This is from this datasheet [here](https://sdr-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/product_info/LS7366R.pdf) on page 11 of 13.

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Comment: Related: *[Schmitt triggers hysteresis symbols](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443463/schmitt-triggers-hysteresis-symbols)*

Comment: Candidates: *[What does this schematic symbol mean (rectangle with two tails, "0.44 VCC_IO" on the bottom, "0.56 VCC_IO" on top)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651466/)* (2023) and *[Alien circuit component](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117828/)* (2014)

Comment: Related: *[What does this symbol mean? (like a comparator, but there is another symbol in this triangle)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366851/)*

Comment: fwiw that's a pretty poor drawing of a schmitt trigger.  Easy enough to see when you know what it is, but any less tail and it really would just be a rectangle inside a buffer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> strange symbol in this IC block diagram that looks like a rectangle inside a buffer

It's a "Schmitt trigger."

A "Schmitt trigger" is a type of logic gate that provides hysteresis. It is used to convert a noisy input into a clean digital output. The Schmitt trigger has two threshold voltages: an upper threshold (V_T+) and a lower threshold (V_T-). When the input signal crosses the upper threshold, the output changes state, and it doesn't change back until the input drops below the lower threshold. This helps to eliminate noise and provides a stable output, especially for slowly varying or noisy inputs.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the "rectangle symbol" is a miniature depiction of the typical hysteresis plot.

Comment: @EugeneSh. good point, thanks for adding.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a logic inverter with a Schmitt Trigger action:

[image: Schmitt Trigger]

Comment: Nice picture that clearly shows that the "rectangle symbol" is a miniature depiction of the typical hysteresis plot, as @EugeneSh. pointed out